How can i prove a set is not open in topology?
On the plane $\mathbb R^2$ with usual topology, let $F = ${$(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \leq 3, \, x - y < 0$}. Prove $F$ is not open.
So here's what i did:
i prove that $A = ${$(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \leq 3$} is closed because if we put $f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2$. Then $f^{-1}((-\infty,3]))$ is closed since $(-\infty,3]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$.
Then similarly i prove $B = ${$(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x - y < 0$} is open.
Then $F=A\bigcap B$. But it's so confusing because I can't be sure whether $F$ is not open.

For metric spaces, a set $U$ is open if for every $x\in U$ there exists $r > 0$ with $B(x, r)\subseteq U$ where $B(x, r) = {y : d(x, y) < r}$ is an open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. You just need to find a point in $A$ without this property

Hi, welcome to Math SE. To expand on @Jakobian's point: as a rule, if $\le$ or $\ge$ appears in the definition of a locus, you can prove it's not open by showing points saturating the inequality aren't the centres of neighbourhoods.

Also, your argument needs amplification -- the intersection of a closed set and an open set can be open.  For example, if the closed set is a subset of the open set: $[0,1] \cap (-10,10)$ is open.  You would need to show that at least one boundary point of the closed set is a boundary point of the intersection -- and that's pretty much the same as the method Jakobian describes.

can y'all give me the detailed proof?

@EricTowers Did you have a typo?  $[0,1] \cap (-10,10) = [0,1]$ is definitely not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

@BrianMoehring : Yes.  D'oh.  Was thinking "$(0,1) \cap [-10,10]$".  Good catch.

Thanks to the comment of Pika, following this answer, which indicated that I should have chosen the point $~\displaystyle \left( ~0, ~\sqrt{3}, ~\right) ~$ rather than the point $~\displaystyle \left( ~\sqrt{3}, ~0 ~\right).$  Answer edited.

The way that I was taught, in $~\Bbb{R^2},~$ a set is open if and only if every element in the set is an interior point.  So, to prove that the set is not open, it is sufficient to explicitly show a point in the set that is not an interior point, and then prove that it is not an interior point.
I will choose the point $~(x,y) = P = \displaystyle \left( ~0, ~\sqrt{3}, ~\right).$
So, the entire problem reduces to showing that $~P~$ is not an interior point.  As I understand it, a point $~P~$ is an interior point, if and only if there exists some neighborhood of radius $~r~$ around the point $~P~$ such that the entire neighborhood is in the set.
Take any $~r > 0.~$ Then, any such neighborhood of radius $~r~$ around the point $~P~$ must contain the point $~\left( ~0, \sqrt{3} + r ~\right),~$ which is not in the set.  Since this will hold true for any $~r > 0,~$ the point $~P~$ is not an interior point.
Therefore, since the point $~P~$ is in the set, and is not an interior point, the set can not be an open set.

the point you choose should be $(x,y)=(0, \sqrt{3})$???

I totally understand your proof. I hope it's correct

@pika Answer edited to accommodate your comment.
